# Bring Window to Current Space in macOS

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3, osx-spaces

**Background** I've been using macOS's "Spaces" feature for years, and it's great. After trying a few different configurations, I use four Spaces: main work (e.g,. Xcode, Sketch), documents (Pages), internet & media (e.g., Firefox, Music, Postbox), and then task-tracking and file stuff (e.g., Excel, Finder, Terminal).

The issue I run into is that I use Sublime *so much* and end up having Sublime documents open everywhere. It's a mess. I can occasionally merge all my windows into one tabbed window, but because those different documents relate to tasks on different Spaces they all just end up pulled out again.

**Question**
I'd like to setup a keyboard shortcut that pulls that big tabbed Sublime window to whatever Space I'm in. Any idea how I can do this? (I currently use Keyboard Maestro and BetterSnapTool, but happy with solutions that require other apps or Terminal too.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Mac OSX - Natively.

This is a very common question in fact, with many users wanting the ALT+TAB type behaviour that exists in Windows but for OSX. Yet, still Apple have not added it as a feature - which is to say the least bizarre.

So no, you cannot natively control the positional appearance of application windows with shortcuts. However, if you're willing to pay for it you can get what you want with an application like [Witch](https://manytricks.com/witch/).

There are many third party apps that do this so the choice is yours.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Witch, hadn't seen that before. That said, I'm looking for the other way around: pulling another application's window to the current space. Many of these tools (e.g., Amethyst) work in the other direction: sending the current window to a specified Space. My search continues…

Comment: Worth downloading a trial of Witch and testing it. Perhaps emailing their support team to double check that as matter-of-factly. You never know, they may be able to advise you that it can bring a window to the current space without switching to the space it resides in.